# Refresh EFI entries that show under efibootmgr

Tags: boot, uefi, bootable-media, efi

When I type `efibootmgr` into the terminal I get output that looks a little something like this:

```
0001 Ubuntu
0002 Windows
1001 Random Partition 1
1002 Random Partition 2
1003 Random Partition 3
```

Now if I plug in a bootable USB into my PC, I would like to see the new entry show up when I run the command again, like so:

```
0001 Ubuntu
0002 Windows
1001 Random Partition 1
1002 Random Partition 2
1003 Random Partition 3
0003 Bootable USB
```

However, the new efi entry wont show up unless I reboot my computer with the USB stick plugged in. Is there any way I can "refresh" the EFI so that it can see the USB without a reboot? I looked in the manual for efibootmgr but couldn't find anything that was useful. I saw that you could create an efibootmgr entry... could I perhaps create an entry that maps to that USB? Note: I want to be able to automate this process, so I would need to be able to detect the USB and create the entry without actually having to type in the configuration information.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firmware of your computer is creating UEFI variable while booting for devices that are available while booting. Once the operating system calls ExitBootServices() the firmware is not managing these devices anymore and therefore cannot update the variables.

You could write a udev rule that calls a script invoking efibootmgr to create an additional Bootxxxx variable when a USB plug event occurs. Cf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in

Comment: OK. not the ideal solution but going off of the research and your comment I believe it is the only way. Thanks.